# What role does the cathode resistance play in a non-contact voltage detector?

Tags: bjt

[image]

I built a real circuit based on this non-contact voltage meter that I often see on the internet and I saw that the circuit works well, but I'm still not sure what role the cathode resistance plays in that circuit. As a result of the simulation, it seems that there is no difference in the result value with or without cathode resistance. Why is there a large-capacity cathode resistance of 1 MΩ?

Comment: 허윤제 - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that original content must be correctly referenced. The source webpage (not just website name) or PDF etc. should be linked as a minimum (references for books / articles should include title, author(s), publisher, edition, page numbers etc.). Please edit your question to include the required source link for the image you included. Thanks. (You can remind yourself of the main site rules by reading the [tour] & [help].)

Answer (score 3):

Data sheets for BC547 don't specify **absolute maximum rating** for base current, but the [Fairchild](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/BC546.pdf) data sheet does plot the base-emitter data:

[image: plot of base-emitter voltage/current for BC547 transistor]

 This is typical for this class of small transistor. A data sheet for another similar transistor *does specify* absolute maximum base current of 50 mA.

That last transistor (Q3) might see **a lot** of base current due to current gain of Q1 multiplied by that of Q2. The respective collector resistors on Q1, Q2 limit the maximum base current that Q3 sees.

R1, R2 are there to protect Q3 from base over-current. The circuit would likely work OK if they were shorted-out, but Q3 is then at risk of destruction.
R1 also protects Q1's base-collector junction should the probe voltage exceed the 9V DC supply.

Answer (score 1):

\$R_1\$ is likely more a practical matter of availability and construction than about some theoretical situation. The circuit likely would still work well enough with \$R_1=10\:\text{M}\Omega\$ (even though the \$\beta\$ for \$Q_1\$ may be somewhat lower than normal.) The problem with high-valued resistors, those particularly more than about \$4.7\:\text{M}\Omega\$, is availability and contamination (such as dirt, finger oils, humidity and clinging moisture which make it nearly pointless without good care given to the construction process.) It's easier to just specify a value that is likely available and achievable without requiring such care.

Resistor values that are exact powers of 10 are very common and easily found. In fact, this circuit uses ***only*** such values. I don't think this was an accident. I think it is intentional. (For example, the LED could be set for a slightly higher current. But that would require a resistor value that wasn't an exact power of 10.)

Skipping over to the other end of the circuit for a moment, note that \$Q_3\$ needs to drive an LED and a buzzer. The buzzer helps keep the LED **off** when \$Q_3\$'s ability to sink current is limited by low base current.

A buzzer may need about \$30\:\text{mA}\$. The LED another \$7\:\text{mA}\$, perhaps. So the collector load for \$Q_3\$ is likely no more than about \$40\:\text{mA}\$. However, if the collector can only supply \$\frac1{10}\$th that much, or \$4\:\text{mA}\$, it's likely that the buzzer will consume it without making much sound and this fact will also then keep the LED from lighting up.

Without the buzzer, smaller base currents may still allow enough \$Q_3\$ collector current to make the LED visible. So, the buzzer is probably also a *good idea* for the circuit. It means that everything important happens within a factor of 10 for \$Q_3\$'s base current and that the behavior is better managed by the design.

Given the worst case \$\beta=110\$ and typical of \$\beta=200\$ for the [Fairchild BC546/547/548/549/550](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/BC546.pdf), \$Q_3\$ can be considered **off** when the base current is \$\le 25\:\mu\text{A}\$ and definitely **on** when the base current is \$\ge 100\:\mu\text{A}\$.

Note that \$R_2\$ is set to provide, at most, about \$90\:\mu\text{A}\$. This seems about right. Certainly, it's not too far afield. And, of course, \$R_2\$ is one of those power-of-ten values which are very readily found. So that choice is clear enough, I think.

This brings us back to \$R_1\$'s value. It's likely that \$Q_2\$'s \$\beta\$ value will be sufficient even with larger values for \$R_1\$. But construction and availability details make selection of a larger value of little added value. (Resistor packs often don't include values much above \$1\:\text{M}\Omega\$, for example.) And there's no real benefit from a reduced base drive into \$Q_2\$. Better to just specify easily accessed values that can be readily found and then constructed by almost anyone.

There are other possible considerations for changing the circuit, but I don't think they impacted this design. I think the designer selected power-of-ten values for the resistors with purpose and intent for a very wide audience. The fact that you've been successful with it just adds supporting testimony to those design decisions.

I'm kind of impressed, all things considered, by the balancing act performed in this design.