# What is the role of resistance in a voltage tester?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt

[image]

In the pspice simulation, the result values with and without 1M and 100k resistors were the same.
I wonder how those resistors work in a real circuit.

Comment: 허윤제 - Hi, This question seems to be effectively the same as your [previous one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/669795/what-role-does-the-cathode-resistance-play-in-a-non-contact-voltage-detector). Same schematic, same question about the resistor values etc. Therefore I have closed this question as a duplicate. It is generally not acceptable to have multiple questions with overlapping topics at the same time here, due to the likelihood of wasting the time of site members duplicating effort across those questions. Thanks.