# I would like to know why there is such a number of cathode resistances in this circuit

Tags: transistors, amplifier, resistors, bjt

[image]

As a result of actually making the voltage tester circuit above, I confirmed that the circuit actually works, but I still don't know why 1M and 100k resistors are needed.  Even without those resistors, the circuit worked without problems. Are those resistors necessary because of an overload of the circuit?

Comment: Although not shown in the circuit above, a microcurrent of about 10uA enters the base of the first bjt, and the current is amplified three times to light up the led.

Comment: I edited picture

Comment: Similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/669795/330261), recently.

Comment: Try to find what happens with an input current of 20 mA with/out the collector resistors.

Comment: @Rkfka - Your question is clearly answered in [this answer](/a/669802) to the recent, almost identical, question (with lots of useful explanations in all answers on that question).